# C - Adding to linked list within a list node

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I am having difficulty figuring out how to add elements to a list attribute I have within nodes in a linked list, particularly with how to set up the pointers.

I have a struct like so:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *elements;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;
 Node *mainlist;
 Node *elemlist;
```

And I want to be able to find a specific Node in mainlist, and add all the elements from elemlist into that nodes *elements.

I have this function which takes in mainlist and a value to check for:

```
void add_elements(Node *mainlist, int value)
{
    Node *ptr = mainlist;
    Node *ptr2 = elemlist;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
            if(value == ptr->value)
            {
                    while(ptr2 != NULL)
                    {
                            Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                            newNode->value = ptr2->value;
                            newNode->next = ptr->elements;
                            ptr->elements = newNode;
                            ptr2 = ptr2->next;
                    }
            }
            ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault so its obviously not adding the elements from elemlist into the node's elements. I'm fairly certain i'm doing something wrong with my pointers.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is this the actual code as `Node->value = ptr2->value;` will not compile.

Comment: There also seems to be inconsistent use of `Node` versus `SymTblNode` - I doubt this is the actual code, which makes it difficult/impossible to diagnose the problem. It would also be quicker/easier all round if the OP learned to use a debugger for such trivial problems.

Comment: If you run this through your compiler, there should be several warnings and errors. Fix these first and ask then again.

Comment: When you have segmentation faults, you should run your program in a debugger. This will help you find _where_ the problem is, and also let you examine variables to help you understand _why_ it might crash.

Comment: 1) the mainlist function argument has the same name as a global variable. This is (at least) a bad habit. 2) you can greatly simplify the code by using for() loops instead of while() loops. 3) you can furher simplify by replacing the `if(eq){blabla} by `if (!eq) continue; blabla` 4) your inner loop copies the elemlist in reversed order and before any existing elements. 5) if the value is unique, you could jump out of the outer loop after the first matched element is processed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this:

```
     Node->value = ptr2->value;
```

should be this:

```
    newNode->value = ptr2->value;
```

Comment: This will cause a compilation failure, not a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

right after calling malloc for your newNode, you should initialize the `value` and the `next` items for that newNode

But you are changing the `Node->value` but you should change the `newNode->value`

---

You must replace `Node->value = ptr2->value;` with `newNode->value = ptr2->value;`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your seg fault will come after your inner while loop has been executed, and as such ptr2 is pointing to the end of its linked list. Then, if the second loop is executed again you're accessing invalid memory. Try resetting ptr2 after the inner loop.

So like

```
void add_elements(Node *mainlist, int value)
{
    Node *ptr = mainlist;
    Node *ptr2 = elemlist;
    Node *tmp = ptr2;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
            if(value == ptr->value)
            {
                    while(ptr2 != NULL)
                    {
                            Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                            newNode->value = ptr2->value;
                            newNode->next = ptr->elements;
                            ptr->elements = newNode;
                            ptr2 = ptr2->next;
                    }
                     ptr2 = tmp;
            }
            ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can simply move the     Node *ptr2 = elemlist; inside the outer while so it is initialized for while's every execution

Answer (score 0):

Dunno why you have a segFault but that's because you are setting newNode->next (or not) with a undefined pointer address.

```
typedef struct Node{
int value;
struct Node *elements;
struct Node *next;
```

}Node;

Node *mainlist;
Node *elemlist;

```
void add_elements(Node* mainlist, int value){
    Node* ptr  = mainlist;
    Node* ptr2 = elemlist;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("* %u\n", ptr->value);
        if(value == ptr->value)
        {
            while(ptr2 != NULL)
            {
                Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                newNode->value  = ptr2->value;
                newNode->next   = ptr->elements;
                ptr->elements   = newNode;
                ptr2            = ptr2->next;
            }
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

        Node* node = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
        Node* node2 = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
        node->next = node2;
        node2->value = 17;
        add_elements(node, 2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is working (even if i have added the element outside the function ;), but take it as an exercise  )